# c# Cannot Convert from string to int

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that populates from an SQL table and shows two columns, one comes from an integer data column, the other from an nvarchar. Gridview also has a checkbox column

The gridview populates correctly, and after a subset of rows is selected (via checkbox column) I want to insert the selected rows into another SQL table. When populating the variables for the SQL statement however I get the "Cannot Convert from string to int" error on the value that is populated from an int to begin with.

I have tried writing up convert and parse for this statement but still getting the error:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PracticeArea", int.Parse(row.Cells["Id"].Value));

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PracticeArea", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Id"].Value));

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PracticeArea", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Id"].Text));
```

All still show the error on the ["Id"] value.

Any thoughts?

Example of the data that is being populated to the gridview is:

```
PracticeID  PracticeName
1   General Surgical Pathology
2   General Pathology/Basic Science
4   Cardiovascular
6   Cytopathology-GYN
7   Cytopathology-nonGYN
```

Full button command is:

```
protected void Bulk_Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
        {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ReviewerPractice VALUES(@Reviewer, @PracticeArea)", con))  
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reviewer", ReviewerName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PracticeArea", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Id"].Value));
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full Gridview control is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="PracticeName" HeaderText="PracticeName"  ItemStyle-Width="150" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Add Practice Areas" OnClick="Bulk_Insert" runat="server" />
```

Hope this answers (some?) of the questions from all the comments to date.

Comment: Could you debug and see what value is for row.Cells["Id"].Value?

Comment: @GiladGreen leading and trailing white space is handled by the parser.

Comment: I affraid `Id` is not the value which throw this error. Do you have some other `Integer` column in your target database table?

Comment: 1) Don't use `AddWithValue` - it can mess things up. 2) Can you show us a sample of `row.Cells["Id"].Value`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, it will not mess up with `int.Parse(row.Cells["Id"].Value)`

Comment: Can you please include the entire exception and stack trace and the value of `row.Cells["Id"].Value` and `row.Cells["id"].Text`?

Comment: @Fabio Depends on how `@PracticeArea` is being used as it will end up typing it dynamically instead of statically http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: ADO.NET have mapped `int32` of .NET to `INT` of Sql type. So I don't  think it will mess up with integer. But your suggestion is valuable - better do not use `AddWithValue`

Comment: This is an issue that a simple run through the debugger could solve in a jiff. Could you run your code through a debugger and check what rows are passed to this code and what is the value of the cell at the point of the exception?

Comment: Use Int.TryParse to pass a default value on parse failure

Comment: Great question with plenty of initial info, 9 comments, and 0 up-votes? Why don't people up-vote things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `row.Cells[]` is an array, so you need to use it like this:

```
row.Cells[3].Text
```

And it's better to use the Parameters for sql like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PracticeArea", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[index].Text;
```

Comment: I cannot get either of the formats that you have provided to work. Both are still giving an error. Only change is that now it is a "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' error.

Comment: That means you are trying to access a cell  that does not exist in the Array of Cells. If for example a GridView has 4 columns (0, 1, 2, 3) and you are trying to access the 5th `row.Cells[4].Text` you will get that error.

Comment: Cancel last comment, with some tweaking it is working now.